# How to copy Data from a data class to an object in C#.(Unity)

Tags: c#

I want to define a method to copy data from another data class to  a new defined object and then return it. For example:

```
public GameData Gett() {
    point pt = new point();
    return pt;
}

public class point : GameData
{
    public int TouchGround;
}
```

So what should I do to copy the data from TouchGround to pt and then return it as an object?

Answer (score 1):

If your objects basically have some primitive type properties, your data classes like Point (should be uppercase!) could implement the ICloneable interface. That means mapping the data by hand:

```
class Point : ICloneable
{
    public int TouchGround;

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new Point
        {
            TouchGround = this.TouchGround
        }
    }
}
```

If you have to copy alot of properties on different classes, you could utilize a framework like automapper (http://automapper.org/).
It allows you to do something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Point, Point>();
var point = new Point();
Mapper.Map<Point, Point>(existingPoint, point);
```

Another option would be creating your data objects as structs. Structs are copied on assignment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs

Answer (score 1):

For shallow copy, you can use MemberwiseClone() method available in C#  ICloneable interface. So, your point class should be changed to this.

```
public class point : GameData,  ICloneable
{
    public int TouchGround;

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

For shallow copy, you can use this.

```
    point a = new point();
    a.TouchGround = 1;

    // Next lines, create a shallow copy of a and put into b.
    point b = (point)a.Clone();
    b.TouchGround = 20;

    Console.WriteLine(a.TouchGround);
    Console.WriteLine(b.TouchGround);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

For deep copy, you would need to serialize this class and then de-serialize as another object of same type. You can do this using Newtonsoft.JSON. Your class should be serializable. [Check this for similar details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591544/object-deep-clone-implementation). You can also use [DataContractSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/serialization-guidelines).

```
    point x = new point();
    x.TouchGround = 35;

    point y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<point>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x));
    y.TouchGround = 40;

    Console.WriteLine(x.TouchGround);
    Console.WriteLine(y.TouchGround);
    Console.ReadLine();
```