# Do we need to use asp.net Auto Mapper if the source and destination types are the same

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I was reading about the convention-based object-object mapper in .NET https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper . which allow to map the properties between two objects. but my question is when we need to use this mapper? let say in my code the source and destination objects have the same type, then do i need this mapper?
For example, i can map objects with the same type using the straightforward `=` operation, as follow:-

```
Staff source = new Staff ()
{
FirstName= "Source First",
LastName = "Source Last",
Age =22,
Address = "Soruce 123..."
};

Staff destination = new Staff ()
{
FirstName= "Destination First",
LastName = "Destination Last",
Age =20,
Address = "Destination 123..."
};

source = destination;
entities.Staffs.Add(source);
entities.Save();
```

where in this case the source object will be saved with the destination properties? and i do not have to use auto mapper ? is this correct ?

Comment: I typically use AutoMapper to map between DTOs and Models. Property names don't always line up and some DTOs may have properties flattened.

Comment: In this case you don't have a new instance and you lose the reference to the original `source`. AM would clone the object so you get two instances. Of course, if you do this routinely, it's better to implement `ICloneable`.

Comment: I'd say never use Automapper and instead do explicit mapping, but thats just me.

Comment: @UrbanEsc why now if we have 20++ properties,, then doing explicit mapping will be very handy ..

Comment: Even if (or especially if) you have 100 properties, explicitly mapping will take some time up front, sure, but debugging errors will be so much easier. Also you get compile time checks for free if any property changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `source = destination;`, that will copy reference of the memory location for destination object only. In the example you have provided, it does not really matter since you are adding object to entities.

If you want a complete clone of object at separate memory location to do other processing with the object, use ICloneable and MemberwiseClone, in case, you do not want to use AutoMapper for stuff where mapping is exactly the same.

```
public class Staff : ICloneable
{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public int Age{get;set;}
    public string Address{get;set;}

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Then, you can use `source = (Staff)destination.Clone();`

This will allow shallow copy only. If you want deep copy, [you can serialize and deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46643446/7974050).

Comment: but what will be the issue with just doing things as follow 
`source = destination;` ?? what i need is to save the source object inside the database, with the same values as the destinatin

Comment: For class objects, when you say `source = destination`, it does not copy its properties value by value, instead it will take memory location of `destination` object and save that memory location pointer to `source` object's pointer. That means, you would have 2 objects pointing to same memory location on heap. Make change in one, it will reflect in both. You would rather have 2 objects, each of which is independent for change in any value.

Comment: It works fine in your case because you are simply adding it to entities for DB save, but for general code, it is incorrect approach.

Comment: so you mean it is better to use automapper in this case? so even if the source and destination are the same it is advisable to use auto mapper ?

Comment: Yes. It is not a bad idea to use Automapper as a convention for mapping from source to DB and back. People do explicit mapping as well. They create 2 objects, and copy each property value by value. They call it mapper layer. Something like, `source.FirstName = destination.FirstName` and so on....

Comment: i know that i can do explicit mapping `source.FirstName = destination.FirstName` but we use the automapper or other appraoches to make our code looks better, and remove manual steps..

Answer (score 1):

Since you have some questions, i'll try to answer them separately:

> when we need to use this mapper?

You use an AutoMapper when you want to set a number of properties of an object, based on the properties of another object (which can be of the same type, although usually this is not the case).

> let say in my code the source and destination objects have the same type, then do i need this mapper?

It depends on whether you want the source object to remain the same (i.e: the object reference) and you want to copy all the type's properties. If this is not the case, then an AutoMapper can still useful in this case (even when both types are the same).

> For example, i can map objects with the same type using the straightforward = operation

They are not equivalent operations. The assignment operator (`destination = source`) replaces the object reference, so the variable `destination` will then reference the same object as the variable `source` (`Object.referenceEquals(source, destination) == true`).

If you use `Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source, destination)`, you are essentially setting all the properties of the `source` object, but it's still the same object (`Object.referenceEquals(source, destination) == false`).

Comment: but at the end when i save the source object, the values which get saved inside the DB is the same as the destination values.. and this what i need ....

Comment: @jonh G, yes, if you want to copy all the properties and you don't care about having two objects then yes, AutoMapper is unnecessary :)